# Python DataFrame Multiple Column Groupby With Max Value From First Group

Tags: python, dataframe

Data Frame is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,'a','c1',30,'s1','e1'],[1,'b','c1',60,'s1','e1'],[1,'b','c2',40,'s1','e1'],[2,'g','c1',40,'s2','e2'],[2,'g','c3',9,'s1','e1'],[3,'k','c2',20,'s1','e1'],[3,'k','c2',69,'s2','e1'],[3,'k','c1',29,'s1','e1'],[3,'f','c3',99,'s2','e1']], columns = ['Lot','Item','Code','Date','Shelf','Emp'])
```

```
     Lot Item Code  Date Shelf Emp
0    1    a   c1    30    s1  e1
1    1    b   c1    60    s1  e1
2    1    b   c2    40    s1  e1
3    2    g   c1    40    s2  e2
4    2    g   c3     9    s1  e1
5    3    k   c2    20    s1  e1
6    3    k   c2    69    s2  e1
7    3    k   c1    29    s1  e1
8    3    f   c3    99    s2  e1
```

I need to

1. Group By Lot and then Item
2. Get the First Item in each Lot
3. Finally Get the Max Date for each First Item in Each Lot

The OUTPUT should be:

```
     Lot Item  Code Date Shelf Emp
0    1    a    c1   30   s1    e1
3    2    g    c2   40   s2    e1
6    3    k    c2   69   s2    e1
```

Thank you !!!

Comment: Sorry !! Finally Get the Max Date FROM each First Item( GROUP ) in Each Lot

Comment: Do you need to keep the original index (0,3,6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using a few intermediary steps (there may be a simpler way, but this is how I would do it).

Firstly, group your df by Lot and return the first item for each lot using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to create a temporary df:

```
temp_df1 = df.groupby('Lot', as_index=False).first()[['Lot', 'Item']]

   Lot Item
0    1    a
1    2    g
2    3    k
```

I then used [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the original df onto temp_df to get only the rows from df that contain the first item for each lot:

```
temp_df2 = df.merge(temp_df1, on=['Lot', 'Item'], how='inner')

     Lot Item Code  Date Shelf Emp
0    1    a   c1    30    s1  e1
1    2    g   c1    40    s2  e2
2    2    g   c3     9    s1  e1
3    3    k   c2    20    s1  e1
4    3    k   c2    69    s2  e1
5    3    k   c1    29    s1  e1
```

Then you can group by Lot and Item on this data frame to get your desired output

```
df_out = temp_df2.groupby(['Lot', 'Item'], as_index=False).max()

   Lot Item Code  Date Shelf Emp
0    1    a   c1    30    s1  e1
1    2    g   c3    40    s2  e2
2    3    k   c2    69    s2  e1
```

Full code:

```
temp_df1 = df.groupby('Lot', as_index=False).first()[['Lot', 'Item']]
temp_df2 = df.merge(temp_df1, on=['Lot', 'Item'], how='inner')
df_out = temp_df2.groupby(['Lot', 'Item'], as_index=False).max()
```

Or the below without creating temporary dfs:

```
df_out = (df.merge(df.groupby('Lot', as_index=False).first()[['Lot', 'Item']],
                   on=['Lot', 'Item'], how='inner')
          .groupby(['Lot', 'Item'], as_index=False).max())
```

Comment: SUPER ! THANK YOU Emi OB :)

Comment: Umm, Emi OB could you please explain how, without even using Date column we get its Max ?

Comment: @ABCode I assume you mean the final step (`df_out = temp_df2.groupby(['Lot', 'Item'], as_index=False).max()`) If not let me know. If you look at the documentation for groupby (linked in the question) you will see how it works.  In this case we are specifying to group by Lot and Item, hence why they are specified in the group by function.  We then use the .max() function to pick out the maximum within each of these groups for the remaining numerical columns not specified in groupby (i.e. Date)

Comment: Got it thanks ! slight problem. the Data Frame has 3 more fields, that are not showing in output
```
     Lot Item Code Date Shelf Emp
0    1    a      c1    30    s1     e1 
1    1    b      c1   60     s1     e1
2    1    b      d2   40    s2     e1
3    2    g      d6   40    s2     e1 
4    2    g      e2   9      s1    e2
5    3    k      a1   20     s1    e2
6    3    k      b2   69    s2    e2
7    3    k      b3   29    s3    e2
8    3    f      c2    99    s4    e2
```
I omitted them for simplicity.

Comment: If you don't want those columns included, then you can put `[['Lot', 'Item', 'Date']]` at the end

Comment: please check the complete DataFrame.... how to print the rest of the fields?

Comment: @ABCode, apologies you've update the question again. The original answer should've given you what you wanted regardless of the extra columns? I have changed my answer back to the original code and updated the outputs

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Lot']).first()['Item'].reset_index()
df1['Date'] = [df['Date'].loc[df['Item'] == x].max() for x in df1['Date']]
df1
```

Result:

| index | Lot | Item | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | 30 |
| 1 | 2 | g | 40 |
| 2 | 3 | k | 69 |

**Edit:** even better using a "mask" and no temp df

```
m = df.groupby(['Lot']).first()['Item'].tolist()
df[df.Item.isin(m)].groupby(['Lot', 'Item'], as_index=False).max()
```

| index | Lot | Item | Code | Date | Shelf | Emp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | c1 | 30 | s1 | e1 |
| 1 | 2 | g | c3 | 40 | s2 | e2 |
| 2 | 3 | k | c2 | 69 | s2 | e1 |

Comment: @AB Code  I know you already had your answer but let's have a look at my two variants ;)